# How to know ids for html fields on Rails 3?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, html-input

**Stage**:
I am using nested models, supose we have two models: `person` and `car`.
And here you have `new.html.erb` page:

```
<%= form_for(@person do |f| %>
  ...
  <%= f.fields_for :cars do |car| %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= car.label :color %><br />
      <%= car.text_field :color, :maxlength => 7 %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

This code will generate for each car:

```
<form ...>
  ...
  <div class="field">
    <label for="person_cars_attributes_0_color">Car color</label><br />
    <input id="person_cars_attributes_0_color" 
           name="person[cars_attributes][0][color]" 
           size="7" type="text" />
  </div>
  ...
</form>
```

Now suppose we need to put some javascript code for each input field, to generate something like this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready( function() { $('#person_cars_attributes_0_color').mycolorpicker(); });
    </script>
    <input id="person_cars_attributes_0_color" 
           name="person[cars_attributes][0][color]" 
           size="7" type="text" />
```

Notice, we need in javascript code input field `id` (in this example `person_cars_attributes_0_color`).

**Problem**: How can we get this id value for each html field generated?

Thank you very much for your help.
Please feel free to ask me anything if you need more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about assigning the field in question an ID or class that you determine before hand?

`new.html.erb`:

```
<%= form_for(@person do |f| %>
  ...
  <%= f.fields_for :cars do |car| %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= car.label :color %><br />
      <%= car.text_field :color, :maxlength => 7, :class => 'colorpicker' %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.colorpicker').mycolorpicker();
});
```

Comment: It was so easy. Thank you very much. I am too noob here in Javascript and jQuery worlds.

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend checking out the [nested_form](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form) gem by Ryan Bates. I think it will take care of everything that you are looking to do.

Comment: Janders223, Thank you very much for reply. I am going to check it and I will reply back about any progress.

Comment: Hi, I have watched those videos and it is similar but I still do not know how to get a solution to my problem. :(
If you know, please coach me a little bit.

Comment: The javascript behind the nested_form gem will add the appropriate id to each div that you add. Each new div that you then insert would have an id of `person_cars_attributes_new_color`